# Sql Server 2008 Removes 0's from Date

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am using `asp.net/c#` to build an application.I am accepting dates in British Format .
Suppose a user enters a date in the format `02/04/2001` , it gets stored in the table properly.However when i retrieve it the date is coming in this format `4/2/2001`. I know that is coming in American Format , that's ok for me , my issue is that it is removing `0's`from numbers which are single digit. Will i have to check for such numbers and padding a zero before it and then display dates.Is there any way for this.
Thanks

Comment: You should be saving and loading dates to/from the database as `date` or `datetime` values - which don't *have* a format. In turn, in your .NET code you should be storing them as `DateTime` objects (which again, don't *have* a format). You should only convert them to strings (for display) as late as possible in your code.

Comment: To circumvent strongly typed formats using integer values for the date, you may consider changing the column to a string type :P SCNR

Comment: @eFloh - in my experience, probably 80% of date handling issues arise from people treating dates as strings, rather than as an appropriate datatype (data and/or datetime)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - you are totally right, I should have marked my comment with even more sarcasm tags ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can format a date retrieved from SQL Server in .Net without worrying about the underlying value. Use culture-specific formatting if desired.

[Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)
[Custom Date Time Formats in .Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)
[Formatting Date and Time for a Specific Culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya.aspx)

Just to be clear (per Damien's comment) I am making the assumption that you are storing your values as `Dates`, `DateTimes`, `DateTime2s`, etc. in SQL **not** as strings. If that's not the case, conversion to a proper type should be the first step.